Why can't "dig" on rockylinux 9 find a container/host named "https" in a docker compose network?
Sorry I don't know if this is a docker issue or a dig issue on rockylinux 9. Everything works as expected on rockylinux 8.
I have a docker-compose.yml file below with a service named https. That allows the container to be referenced by the hostname https. While ping https works, for some reason dig https (DiG 9.16.23-RH) does not work on rockylinux 9. It does work on rockylinux 8 (DiG 9.11.36-RedHat-9.11.36-16.el8_10.2). If I change the service name to httpsx then dig httpsx works.
services:
  https:
    image: "rockylinux:${RL_VERSION}"
    command: bash -c "yum install -y iputils bind-utils && echo '=====dig version output====' && dig -v && echo '=====ping https output====' && ping -c 3 https && echo '=====dig https output====' && dig +short https"
    environment:
       - RL_VERSION

Working 8:
% RL_VERSION=8 docker-compose up
Attaching to https-1
https-1  | Rocky Linux 8 - AppStream                       5.7 MB/s |  11 MB     00:01    
...
https-1  | Complete!
https-1  | =====dig version output====
https-1  | DiG 9.11.36-RedHat-9.11.36-16.el8_10.2
https-1  | =====ping https output====
https-1  | PING https (172.21.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
https-1  | 64 bytes from c3f0c7a6613c (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.558 ms
https-1  | 64 bytes from c3f0c7a6613c (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
https-1  | 64 bytes from c3f0c7a6613c (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
https-1  | 
https-1  | --- https ping statistics ---
https-1  | 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2025ms
https-1  | rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.040/0.216/0.558/0.241 ms
https-1  | =====dig https output====
https-1  | 172.21.0.2

Failing 9:
% RL_VERSION=9 docker-compose up
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container testhttps-https-1  Recreated                                                                                                    0.2s 
Attaching to https-1
https-1  | Rocky Linux 9 - BaseOS                          2.4 MB/s | 2.4 MB     00:00    
...
https-1  | Complete!
https-1  | =====dig version output====
https-1  | DiG 9.16.23-RH
https-1  | =====ping https output====
https-1  | PING https (172.21.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
https-1  | 64 bytes from 4a2841b5dac9 (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.404 ms
https-1  | 64 bytes from 4a2841b5dac9 (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.117 ms
https-1  | 64 bytes from 4a2841b5dac9 (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.088 ms
https-1  | 
https-1  | --- https ping statistics ---
https-1  | 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2009ms
https-1  | rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.088/0.203/0.404/0.142 ms
https-1  | =====dig https output====
https-1  | c.root-servers.net.
https-1  | l.root-servers.net.
https-1  | e.root-servers.net.
https-1  | d.root-servers.net.
https-1  | i.root-servers.net.
https-1  | b.root-servers.net.
https-1  | g.root-servers.net.
https-1  | m.root-servers.net.
https-1  | a.root-servers.net.
https-1  | f.root-servers.net.
https-1  | h.root-servers.net.
https-1  | j.root-servers.net.
https-1  | k.root-servers.net.


The fact that it is offering the nameservers for .. might indicate that the rockylinux 9 host has no "search" entry in /etc/resolv.conf

This is neither a Rocky issue nor a docker issue, but a dig quirk; I see the same issue on Debian 12 as well.
What you're seeing is a result of how dig parses the command line.  Normally the syntax (in a simple form) may be considered to be dig name [type] but it also accepts. dig [type] name
So if you do something like dig cname foobar it will look for the CNAME resource record (RR) for foobar, same as if you had done dig foobar cname.
If you don't specify a domain then type whole query becomes dig . ns
Now https has been added an RR type, where as it wasn't in the older version.
And this is what is hitting you because in newer versionsdig https will also look like there's no domain name being passed and so will do the . ns lookup.
And we can see this by looking at the output:
% dig https

; <<>> DiG 9.16.23-RH <<>> https
;; global options: +cmd

...

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.                              IN      NS

The answer is to prefix the query with -q.  Now
% dig -q https
...
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;https.                         IN      A

